# Merging multiple rows with same field in column

Tags: php, mysql, mergesort

I am making a leaderboard for a game server and would like a hand with something.

I have a table in MySQL that looks like [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14PL-4L6vuN9f2QzeP8JxFSZf1rwVttbnhhJcLQhy1vs/edit?usp=sharing) (There are other columns that exist but I want to ignore)

Is there a way to combine each row with the same value in `steam_id_64`, but with `player_name` show the last used steam name (Or current from steam) and is it possible to hide the row where `steam_id_64` is `BOT`?

I have php5 if that is helpful. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please make it text (table structure),even if it difficult for you it is helpful for us.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to sum up the different columns using sum() function. To avoid those bot entries you can use a condition to test for player_name is not BOT

```
select
  player_name,
  sum(kills) as kills,
  sum(deaths) as deaths,
  sum(assists) as assists,
  sum(head_shots) as headshots,
  sum(team_kills) as team_kills,
  sum(assists_team_attack) as assist_team_attack,
  sum(damage) as damage,
  sum(hits) as hits,
  sum(shots) as shots,
  sum(last_alive) as last_alive
group by steam_id_64
where steam_id_64 != "BOT"
```

To make later handling convenient I have added "... as field_name" to each sum().

Please try this and refine your question if something is missing.

Comment: this worked but MySQL Workbench was erroring on either group or where depending on what came first. I just removed the where steam_id_64 != "BOT" line and it works as I hoped.
I will remove that line in php when I get to it

Answer (score 0):

use `!=` for hide the row where steam_id_64 is BOT

```
Select * from table where steam_id_64 !='BOT'
```